# Remove an XElement from another XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to remove an `XElement` from a `XDocument`.

The problem is i can't just use the `.Remove()` because my `XDocument` is not the same as the `XElement`.

A very important fact is performance.

Scenario: I have an `XDocument docSource` and I copy this to `XDocument doc`. I select a Node of `docSource` and want to delete this Node in my `doc`.

So far I'm using this workaround (which may also delete some wrong nodes if they got the same Parent Name but this doesn't matter so far):

```
    private static XNode actualNode;
    private static void RemoveNode(XDocument doc)
    {
        doc.Root.Descendants(((XElement)actualNode).Name.LocalName)
                             .Where(e => actualNode.Parent.Name.LocalName.Equals(e.Parent.Name.LocalName))
                             .Remove();
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? And especially a faster way? 
My XDocument has like 1000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well a better way of doing the existing name-based approach would be:

```
doc.Root.Descendants(actualNode.Parent.Name)
        .Elements(actualNode.Name)
        .Remove();
```

Aside from anything else, that's simpler - and doesn't use just the local name. (If the elements are actually in different namespaces, you should take account of that separately IMO.)

But this is still just using "element name and parent name" as a way of identifying an element. Do you have anything else which will identify the element more reliably? Some kind of attribute? I'm assuming you actually have some idea of what kind of element you'll be finding.

> My XDocument has like 1000 lines.

Then it should be blink-of-an-eye quick anyway. Do you actually have any indication that this is causing a performance problem?

Another thing to consider:

> Scenario: I have an XDocument docSource and I copy this to XDocument doc. I select a Node of docSource and want to delete this Node in my doc.

Is there any reason you don't just avoid copying the node to start with?

Comment: Performance problem: Yes if I just don't use this single Method my performance runs from 700ms to 200ms so this line consumes huge performance.

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep: That seems a little odd if it's really only 1000 lines. This definitely isn't JIT compilation etc? I really wouldn't expect your current code to cause a problem - although the code I've given may well perform better anyway.

Comment: You're right the shown code was not the problem. There was a misstake in the recursion which called the method like 100.000 times.

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly said, if you just rely on the Parent.Name.LocalName you may end up deleting incorrect child nodes when there are Parents with similar names.

If you validate for repeated parent nodes before deleting the child nodes you will be able to over come this issue.

You should be able to achieve accuracy by loading the nodes to an array/list. Then you will be able to find the position of the exact parent node. But I am afraid it will not improve the performance.

For an example you have 3 parent nodes with 'XZY'.
User selects the 2 parent node. So your parent index will be 1(assuming the index starts with 0)
So you should only delete the children under parent index 1.

Hope this helps.